# JDBC over SSL to a Cache database

Tags: ssl, jdbc, intersystems-cache

I'm pretty far out of my depth here, so bear with me. We're using JDBC via com.intersys.jdbc.cachedriver to run stored procedures in Intersystems Cache and get the results in Java. However, there are other clients that connect directly to the Cache using a terminal over telnet. We have to lock down Cache's telnet port so that only telnet over SSL is possible. However, the Cache experts here say that locking down one port in Cache locks them all down, so the Java to Cache connection will also have to use SSL. I understand vaguely that some JDBC drivers support SSL, but I don't see that the Cache one does. What I need to know is:

1. What's needed to configure SSL for the JDBC connections? (We're using JBoss 4.2.3)
2. What about certificates? I assume those have to go somewhere.
3. Is it actually true that locking down the telnet connections is also going lock down JDBC in the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Configuring Java Clients to Use SSL/TLS with Caché](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20102/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCAS_ssltls#GCAS_ssltls_javacli)
2. [Using SSL/TLS with Caché](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20102/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCAS_ssltls)
3. Telnet vs ssh is a question about what the OS allows and only relates to Cache peripherally. It doesn't mean anything regarding items 1 or 2. So in answer to the direct question you are asking, "No".

Comment: Thanks for that link! I was looking for a document like that and couldn't find it. Unfortunately it only covers getting DB connections via the java.sql.DriverManager. I suppose someone, somewhere still does that, but we use a java.sql.Datasource created by JBoss. It's not clear to me how to translate the instructions for one to the other. For question 3, I probably wasn't clear. I'm not asking about OS capabilities. Cache has a setting making SSL required for terminal connections and the System Management Portal. They say that turning that on also turns it on for JDBC connections. Does it?

Comment: Ah... you're talking about the setting "Superserver SSL/TLS Support" where the options are "Disabled", "Enabled", "Required". That wasn't clear to me. Yes, this simply applies to anything that connects to the SuperServer port. I was confused by your description of it as a setting about "telnet connections" (which is only relevant on Windows).

Comment: Sorry to take so long in accepting this answer. I never did find out how to configure a Java DataSource to use SSL to talk to Cache, as opposed to using the DriverManager. I've asked Intersystems, specifically pointing out the document you linked, which implies that it must be possible, but so far no one has replied to me. We're now looking at a workaround now so that we don't have to set the "Superserver" port to require SSL. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
  1. What's needed to configure SSL for the JDBC connections? (We're using JBoss 4.2.3)
```

See http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20102/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCAS_ssltls#GCAS_ssltls_javacli for details. This section doesn't explicitly mention JDBC, but it's true for JDBC (and the reference has been added for the documentation 2011.1 [next release] .)

```
  2. What about certificates? I assume those have to go somewhere.
```

To quote the documentation: "If the client has a private key and certificate, these are stored in the client’s keystore; the keystore can also hold the client’s root CA certificate and any intermediate CA certificates. To authenticate the server, the client may need to have the root CA certificate for the server and any intermediate CA certificates, these can be stored either in the client’s truststore or along with client certificate information in the keystore. For more information on keystores and truststores, see the section “Keystores and Truststores” in the Java Secure Socket Extension (JSSE) Reference Guide."

```
  3. Is it actually true that locking down the telnet connections is also going lock down JDBC in the same way?
```

Yes -- if telnet connections are to *require* TLS, then the superserver TLS setting needs to be Required, which means that you have to use TLS for anything that goes through the superserver (including JDBC). If you just want to *allow* the use of TLS for telnet connections, set the TLS value to Enabled, which allows non-TLS connections by other means (such as JDBC).